# How to uninstall and reinstall anaconda naviator

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, anaconda3

Unfortunately anaconda has been corrupted and I need to uninstall and reinstall anaconda to fix the issue (Anconda navigator application was not opening so i have to uninstall it). I unistalled the anconda. When i have reinstalled it, it didn't installed properly.It is showing error in command prompt when i try to run conda. It is showing error message 'conda is not recognized as internal or external command'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Answer : Anaconda is not installed proprly due to presence of already present application.

Detail Answer :I have found the solution to  this. If your anaconda navigator application or other anaconda features has stoped working and you have already uninstalled it to fix it by reinstalling please don't do that you will going to have a lot of difficulty in that, try to fix that only rather than uninstalling and again installing. But if you have already uninstalled it and want to install it again make sure that you manually delete condas aplication which you will find in c->Users->admin->appdata. try to delete all the anaconda aplication by searching it.And again install it. If finds errors after installing also, so you haven't deleted (manually) properly. (there are pip files(aprox 700MB),conda files which you have to delete manually)